# Simple question about sup of a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

LEt $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$  be a function. Are we allow to perform the following operation?

$$ \sup_{x \in X} f(x) + \sup_{y \in X} f(x) = \sup_{x \in X} \left( f(x) + \sup_{y \in X} f(x) \right) $$

Comment: yes, because $\sup_X f$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Yes, because in general $\sup k+f(x) = k+\sup f(x)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\sup_{x\in X}f(x)+\sup_{y\in X}f(y)=\sup_{x\in X}\left(f(x)+\sup_{y\in X}f(y)\right)$?